# Combined rows based on COUNT and create multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

How can  roll up multiple rows to single row with multiple columns like Table B?

```
Table A

 Partyid Origin
 1       Atm
 1       Auto
 1       Mobile
 1       mobile

Table B

Partyid               COUNT (atm)   COUNT (auto)    COUNT (mobile)
 1                       1                1                2
```

I used this query:

```
SELECT partyid, 
CASE WHEN origin = 'atm'   THEN COUNT (origin) ELSE '0' END AS N_ATM,
CASE WHEN origin = 'auto'  THEN COUNT (origin) ELSE '0' END AS N_auto,
CASE WHEN origin = 'mobile' THEN COUNT (origin) ELSE '0' END AS N_Mobile,

FROM XXX
GROUP BY partyid
```

and brings this results:

```
Partyid COUNT (atm) COUNT (auto)    COUNT (mobile)

1            1          0               0
1            0          1               0
1            0          0               2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `COUNT()` - use `SUM()` instead, like this:

```
SELECT partyid, 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN origin = 'atm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END) AS N_ATM,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN origin = 'auto' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END) AS N_auto,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN origin = 'mobile' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END) AS N_Mobile
FROM XXX
GROUP BY partyid
```